# A desktop Wiki editor/viewer: is there anything out there?

Tags: text-editors, wiki, plaintext

I'm a big user of wikis, mainly Dokuwiki, I really like the clarity and ease of use of simple text files.  However all good wikis seem to require a web-server of some kind; has anyone come across a good desktop wiki editor/viewer that work with plain-text files, and allow me to work with wiki text files just like any other document file type (note: not a desktop wiki running inside a local webserver)

Before you rush to suggest (I hope!) I have done months of research on this and have tried Wixi, Wikidpad, zulupad....

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at http://www.tiddlywiki.com/ it is very cool and runs on your local browser.  If you have something like DropBox or Live Mesh it makes it even better.

> But it's not just a wiki! It has very powerful plugin capabilities, so it can also be used to build new tools. You have full control over how it looks and behaves. For example, TiddlyWiki is already being used as:

```
* A personal notebook
* A GTD ("Getting Things Done") productivity tool
* A collaboration tool
* For building websites (this site is a TiddlyWiki file!)
* For rapid prototyping
* ...and much more!
```

Comment: Wow, TiddlyWiki is pretty friggin' incredible!

Answer (score 4):

There is a free program named [My Desktop Wiki](http://www.upredsun.com/desktop-wiki-editor/my-desktop-wiki.html) from [upredsun](http://www.upredsun.com). I think this is the software you needed.

Another program is [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), it seems to have a wiki plugin, I think you can try it as well.

Comment: I would like to add that [My Desktop Wiki (now known as My Wiki Editor)](http://www.upredsun.com/desktop-wiki-editor/my-desktop-wiki.html) is now shareware, and not freeware. The version downloadable from its website is a 6-day trial version.

Answer (score 3):

[ConnectedText](http://www.connectedtext.com) is a standalone Windows app (commercial) that may meet your needs.  It supports Mediawiki-like markup, categorization and search along with various graphic plugins and scripting support.

Comment: I would like to add that [ConnectedText is shareware](http://www.connectedtext.com/purchase.php), and is not freeware. The version downloadable from its website is a 30-day trial version.

Answer (score 2):

I've enjoyed working with [Zim](http://zim-wiki.org/).  It's cross-platform, though I've only used it on Linux.

Comment: Yep, tried that one too, Dokuwiki is much better...

Answer (score 0):

What don't you like about Wikidpad?
Why don't you want to run a web-based wiki with it's own server? PMWiki works really good for that.

Comment: Sorry, my original post didn't really make clear that I am running a local Dokuwiki installation, and after much tinkering and customization it is working well for my purposes.  I've been using Dokuwiki for over 5 years and it's becoming like an old friend now!

Answer (score 0):

If you follow WikidPad development you will soon notice that is not realiable. I would stick to ConnectedText that has all standard wiki features (many missing in WikidPad) and has many extensions not available in other systems.